# AWS Encrypted EBS Boot Volumes for Windows Instances

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

Is it possible to create an [encrypted ebs boot volume](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-encrypted-ebs-boot-volumes/) for a windows ec2 instance?

This AWS example shows how to copy an unencrypted boot volume, creating an encrypted boot volume:  `aws ec2 copy-image -r us-east-1 -s ami-60b6c60a --encrypted --kmsKeyID arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:012345678910:key/abcd1234-a123-456a-a12b-a123b4cd56ef`

However, when I try this with the [Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Base - ami-c8a9baa2](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00KQOWCAQ) as the source using `aws ec2 copy-image --source-region us-east-1 --source-image-id ami-c8a9baa2 --name 'W12R2_Base_encrypted' --description 'Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Base - ami-c8a9baa2 (encrypted)' --encrypted`, I get the error: "**A client error (InvalidRequest) occurred when calling the CopyImage operation: Images with EC2 BillingProduct codes cannot be copied to another AWS account.**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now possible to do this (as of May 2019). You do not need to copy an AMI.  Instead you can launch an instance with encrypted volumes (boot/ephemeral/ebs) directly from an unencrypted marketplace AMI.

I have not tried to do this with the CLI or programmatically, but it works from the EC2 console using the latest windows server image (Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-Base-2019.08.16)

The "extra steps" that detail creating/copying your own private AMI have been removed from their latest documentation. I could not find any more information on it other than this blog post.

[Launch Encrypted EBS Bcked EC2 Instances from Unencrypted AMI's](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/launch-encrypted-ebs-backed-ec2-instances-from-unencrypted-amis-in-a-single-step/)

Answer (score 3):

You *first* need to create your own private AMI based on this Marketplace AMI. The "BillingProduct" part of the error is the main clue.

In more detail:

1. Launch an instance with this marketplace AMI. [optionally, you can login and modify it.]
2. Use this newly launched instance to create your own private AMI (Create Image)
3. Copy this image and check the Encryption box. Using the CLI, you would use the `copy-image` mode with the `--encrypted` flag.

More info: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Creating_EBSbacked_WinAMI.html